# SUPEE-10570 + CE 1.7.00

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, ce-1.7.0.0, supee-10570

I'm trying to install the 1.7.0.0 version of the patch from this page: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download The patch file is called `PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.7.0.0_v1-2018-02-23-06-37-58.sh`

When I run this patch it errors like so:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 291.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 680 (offset -148 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 827 (offset -148 lines).
...
patching file lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 119.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 130.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php.rej
```

Now, `AccountController.php` has been patched before via SUPEE-6788 and SUPEE-7405, so I kind of understand why that's failing. But `Sendmail.php` has never been changed. To be sure, I re-downloaded 1.7.0.0 and copied the file over and I can confirm that I have the original, core version of `Sendmail.php` yet I get an error when trying to apply the patch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post this there: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215292/security-patch-supee-10570-possible-issues?

Comment: @sv3n I've posted my findings there too, yes.

Comment: @Manoj Deswal - probably a topic that is to be discussed on Meta, but I think this question does not deserve a "duplicate" branding as it is not a general issue with SUPEE-10570. It rather can happen in ne or the other way with any patch when sequences (patch release dates) are not taken into account, hence the bold note in my answer.

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner I've flagged this as OT because Tyler re-posted this there. It's not a general , but a _" possible issue"_ as the other Q is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Sendmail.php has never been changed

Yet it should have been. Namely while applying SUPEE-9652.
See the comparrision of the relevant parts:
[image]

Generally speaking, **make sure you follow the recommended steps of applying all patches in the correct sequence** (don't just patch per will but by release date ;) ).

Also, your issue is mentioned in the patch details linked at the official download page (https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10570):

> If the patch fails to apply while patching
>   lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php, it might mean your Magento
>   installation was previously patched with SUPEE-9652v1 instead of
>   SUPEE-9652v2. The recommended solution is to revert patch SUPEE-9652v1
>   and apply SUPEE-9652v2 prior to applying SUPEE-10570.

**NOTE:** This official information seems to be incorrect as there was never a second version released. Basically You need to make sure that the currently given SUPEE-9652 is applied.

Comment: I'll give that a try. This is what happens when the client doesn't always want to pay to apply patches, unfortunately.

Comment: Where can we download v1 of patch. I see on magento only v2 available?

Comment: @Icon - good point. This information actually seems to be incorrect! There was never a version released after 9652v1!

Answer (score 2):

In Patch It is mentioned that:

If the patch fails to apply while patching lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php, it might mean your Magento installation was previously patched with SUPEE-9652v1 instead of SUPEE-9652v2. The recommended solution is to revert patch SUPEE-9652v1 and apply SUPEE-9652v2 prior to applying SUPEE-10570.