# We saw a blank page at /checkout/cart after applying SUPEE-10570 and compiling

Tags: magento-1.9

My magento version is ver. 1.9.1.0.

We saw a blank page at /checkout/cart after applying SUPEE-10570 and compiling. Just to clarify: With deactivated compiler all things went well, with activated compiler we only could see a blank cart page when **logged in** without any log entries (even after activating all possible logs and developer mode).

Cause:

1. the function getPasswordTimestamp will invoke two times when **logged in** and visit /checkout/cart.
2. disabled compiler both invocation work.
3. enable compiler only the first invocation work, second invocation failed.

can anyone explain and give the good solution?

getPasswordTimestamp function in Mage_Customer_Helper_Data

```
public function getPasswordTimestamp($customerId)
{
    /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->load((int)$customerId);
    $passwordCreatedAt = $customer->getPasswordCreatedAt();

    return is_null($passwordCreatedAt) ? $customer->getCreatedAtTimestamp() : $passwordCreatedAt;
}
```

Comment: check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215292/security-patch-supee-10570-possible-issues/215698#215698

Comment: did't explain and give the good solution

Comment: Bug submitted: https://magento.com/tech-resources/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1866/