# 1.9.3.7 to 1.9.3.8 Upgrade Broke Cart & Checkout for Logged in Customers After Compilation

Tags: compiler, supee-10570, magento-1.9.3.8

We just upgraded from 1.9.3.7 to 1.9.3.8 and getting a blank page when trying to access the cart or add products to it. This happens for logged in customers only and only when compilation is turned on. No log or PHP errors - just a blank page. We found [this](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/152-magento-onlineshop-supee-10570-und-weisse-seite-bei-warenkorb) but not sure how to properly edit the file. Please help with exact instructions on how and what file to edit.

Comment: I am having the EXACT same problem. Only for logged in customers and when compilation is On. I just upgraded to 1.9.3.8 as well. I am using the original RWD theme as well.

Comment: I just installed a FRESH copy of the 1.9.3.8 Magento community edition on my server. This one with absolutely no added extension. Once I compiled, I am getting the same Blank Page on my cart and checkout. I am surprised how come there is so little people coming up with this bug!

Comment: can confirm the issue with compiling enabled... methinks: if you haven't already, it's time to look at opcache or something similar...

Comment: @JamesTsai do you have any error logs? If nobody answers here please open a ticket there: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts.

Comment: Someone added the bug already: https://magento.com/tech-resources/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1866/

Comment: First problems are discussed here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215292/security-patch-supee-10570-possible-issues/215698#215698

Comment: Hello @Dan, Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Found this:

NOTE:
Magento was recently informed about an issue with both patch SUPEE-10570 and Magento versions 1.9.3.8/1.14.3.8 that could result in the inability of customers to complete checkout when trying to register during checkout. Magento is now providing an updated patch (SUPEE-10570v2) that no longer causes this issue. From:
https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10570
Does anyone know weather Magento fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed within 1.9.3.9.
Please use this newer version.