# SUPEE-10570 buggy patch 500 error after enabled compiler Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento1.9.0.1, supee-10570

I am having issue with this new SUPEE-10570 pathch, when I compile after installing the patch. It gives 500 error on customer login, cart and checkout. This issue not appear if compilation is disabled.

Comment: I tried cleaning cache but no use. I revert the Patch by this command 
> sh PATCH_SUPEE-10570_CE_v1.9.0.1_v1-2018-02-28-04-54-29.sh -R

and everything works fine

Comment: Magento please release its correct version. Thanks

Comment: Discussion of know issues with this patch, here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215292/security-patch-supee-10570-possible-issues